# Kotlin: How to utilize Kotlin data structure to write efficient solutions during interview

Tags: kotlin

I got this question on an interview I was doing and flopped at the last part with the Kotlin. I am trying to recreate `fun taskCompleted()` I wanted to see how I can implement it, just to play with it. So this is what I was given

```
data class Article(val title: String, val content: String, val duration: Int, val date: Int)

data class StreakInfo(val goalsMet: Int, val breakDown: List<Boolean>)

interface ReadingGoalService{
    fun getDailyReadingGoal(): Int
}

interface TaskService{

    fun allTasks(): List<Article>
}

class MockInterview{

   
    fun taskCompleted(){}

    //temporary
    private fun today(): Int{

        return 1
    }
}

fun getAllSteaks(streakInfo: StreakInfo){
    //don't implement
}
```

The ask was to do `fun taskCompleted()` where, I was expected to the following

```
        //TODO 1 current day is today
        //TODO 2 take all the articles that were read on the current day
        //TODO 3 sum readingDurations of articles for current Day
        //TODO 4 check if sum of readingDurations is >= than reading goal
        // TODO 5 if sum of readingDuration is >= goal repeat 2..3.. and 4. for currentDay-1
        //TODO 6 if sum of readingDuration is < goal - stop
```

Any ideas how I can do this in Kotlin? I plan on using this as a learning process.

Comment: I highly suggest you take a look at the [Kotlin Koans](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/koans.html) since they walk you through many examples that I think would certainly teach you how to perform almost all of those TODO's! (and they have the solutions!)

Comment: Thank you, I am using them. I found their data different since they don't use an interface as in this question. I love the ```Shop``` examples though.

Comment: I even created my own testing data ```fun getDifferentCitiesFromCustomer(customers: Shop) {
    val getCustomerCities = customers.customer.map { it.city }

    println("Customer Cities: $getCustomerCities")
}```

Comment: @SomerandomITboy any idea how I can solve that? I will try to create similar problems once I know how I can solve this one. Lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned, I highly suggest you take a look at the Kotlin Koans since they walk you through many examples that I think would certainly teach you how to perform almost all of those TODO's! (and they have the solutions!)

In this interview were testing whether you knew on how to use the aggregate and mapping functions from the Kotlin Standard Library and checking whether you would see that there was a lot of code that you could re-use by making them functions with the right amount of parameters

Here's how I would approach it:

```kotlin
fun today() = 1 // TODO 1: Current day is today

fun tasksDoneByDay(taskService: TaskService, day: Int = today()): List<Article> {
    // TODO2: Here I have all tasks that were done at "today()"
    return taskService.allTasks().filter { task -> task.date == day }
}

// TODO 3
fun durationsForDay(taskService: TaskService, day: Int = today()) = tasksDoneByDay(taskService, day).sumBy { it.duration }


// TODO 4
fun durationsForDayMeetGoal(taskService: TaskService, goal: Int, day: Int = today()) = durationsForDay(taskService, day) >= goal

// TODO 5 if sum of readingDuration is >= goal repeat 2..3.. and 4. for currentDay-1

fun todo5(taskService: TaskService, goal: Int) {
  val today = today()
  return when(val durationsForTodayMeetGoal = durationsForDayMeetGoal(taskService, goal, today)) {
    false -> durationsForDayMeetGoal(taskService, goal, today - 1)
    true -> durationsForTodayMeetGoal
  }
}

// TODO 6 I don't understand...

essentially the same as todo five but when it's false dont do anything?
```

Comment: Interesting, the way I understood is I thought she wanted me to do all that in one function. The ```fun taskCompleted()``` like an algorithm. But what you have done is cool. Let me read that too.

Comment: Like not have them as todo as 5 different functions. Just one that does all that.

Comment: In this case just call function "todo5()" and you're done. It's good to have everything into functions because you can write unit-tests for each of the functions to have more granularity of which function may have a bug in it. If you write everything into a single function it does the same but if something goes wrong you're not really sure which line of code is responsible for the bug

Comment: Ooh yeah that makes sense. How does ```durationsForCurrentDay``` look like? it's complaining on my end

Comment: Sorry, I've refactored that give me a second to put it back together

Comment: Done, it should've been: durationsForDay(taskService, day)

Comment: Thank you very much, you are amazing. I aspire to be like you.

Comment: That's flattering thank you for your kind words :). You'll be the same or even better with some more experience. I've been actively doing Kotlin for three years so I have _some_ experience with it :)